# How blazor components detect if an event method is async or not

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor-server-side

Let's suppose this 2 methods:

```
private void Method1()
{
   ...
}

private async Task Method2()
{
   ...
}
```

Here is how I have to call this methods:

```
Method1();
await Method2();
```

I cannot do that:

```
await Method1();
Method2();
```

Now let's imagine a component with an event:

```
<MyComponent OnEvent="Method1" />
<MyComponent OnEvent="Method2" />
```

In this case, there is no need to put an await for async method.
My question is how blazor can detect if the method used in the event is async or not ?

Thanks

Comment: `how blazor can detect` - because it returns a `Task`, or does not? It does not matter if the method is async. It only matters whether it returns a `Task`. A non-async method that returns a `Task` can be awaited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Method1 is void. This is not a Task....

Comment: ... so Blazor won't try to await it.